# XML Parsing & T-SQL -- Part 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

The xml return, in part is as follows:

```
<Order xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d1p2="http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/package/1.0" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/batch/1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/base/1.0" intendedUse="0" quoteBack="5062-JA$181-3282" d1p1:transactionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" d1p2:uri="asdfasd-afdadfs-adsasdf" d1p1:customerId="0" d1p1:userId="0" d1p1:enabled="false" d1p1:priority="Low" d1p1:frequency="0" d1p1:recordCount="0" d1p1:executionPeriod="Once">
  <Security xmlns="http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/security/1.0">
    <RootCredentials username="ust_3dResults2" password="1234567" />
    <LocationID>abcd</LocationID>
    <AccountID>9876</AccountID>
    <CustomerUserReferenceID>ssmart</CustomerUserReferenceID>
  </Security>
</Order>
```

Using t-sql, how would I pull the "AccountID" for example?  I've tried:

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd, DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
SELECT adr.id, 
adr.omlinput,
adr.omlinput.value('(/Order/Security/AccountID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Results]
FROM [Reporting].[ApplicantDirectRequest] adr WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE adr.OmlInput IS NOT NULL
```

and

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd, DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
SELECT adr.id, 
adr.omlinput,
adr.omlinput.value('(/xsd:Order/Security/AccountID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Results]
FROM [Reporting].[ApplicantDirectRequest] adr WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE adr.OmlInput IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/security/1.0' AS ns, 
                    'http://schemas.abccompany.com/oml/base/1.0' AS base)
SELECT 
    adr.id, 
    adr.omlinput.value('(/base:Order/ns:Security/ns:AccountID)[1]', 'int') AS [Results]
FROM 
    [Reporting].[ApplicantDirectRequest] adr
WHERE 
    ID = 1
```

The tricky part is: the `<Order>` element has the `base` namespace, while everything below it (the `<Security>` and `<AccountID>` elements) have the `ns` namespace.

Since no namespace extends over the whole XML fragment, you cannot really use a **default** namespace....

Comment: That did it, Marc!  If I may trouble you for an explanation of how you came up with this solution that would be a bonus for me.

Comment: @JohnWaclawski: you gotta carefully look at the namespaces that are defined. Those **without** prefix will be automatically applied to the XML element they're defined on (and anything below them, unless overridden). Then check all namespaces **with** prefixes and see where they are applied to XML elements. Those that aren't used anywhere (like those with the `xsi` and `xsd` prefix in your case) can be left out - the other need to be defined

Comment: If I have a element within my xml...example: 
<Subject key="" package-uri="" role="Primary">
how would that be incorporated into my t-sql?
Let's say it's 
<Subjects>
    <Subject key="" package-uri="" role="Primary">
      <FirstName>Ron</FirstName>
      <LastName>Burgandy</LastName>
    </Subject>
  </Subjects>

Comment: @JohnWaclawski: if an XML element doesn't define a *default* XML namespace (`xmlns="..."` without any prefix) and doesn't have a prefix on it, then it's part of the XML namespace that applies to its parent node (which might not be defined on the parent node directly, but further on up in the hierarchy)